# Getting time and defining different variables with it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function in which I am getting the time. Then setting variables to define morning, noon and evening. Finally calling the variables with the greeting variable.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong with the `morningTime` variable. The `noonTime` variable does work.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogmk9fkh/)

```js
 function timeNow() {
  
        var d = new Date(),
        h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours() : '') + d.getHours(),
        m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : '') + d.getMinutes();

        // To check for a time range (between 4:: and 11:30 here):
        var morningTime = (h >= 5 && h <= 12) ? true : false;
        var noonTime    = (h >= 12 && h <= 17) ? true : false;
        var nightTime   = (h >= 17 && h <= 5)  ? true : false;
        var greeting = "";

        if (morningTime) {
            greeting = "Good Morning";
        } else if (noonTime) {
            greeting = "Good Afternoon";
        } else if (nightTime) {
            greeting = "Good Evening";
        }

        return greeting;
    }
    document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow() + ', name!';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard-hello" class="section-title"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see any particular problems with this code and how it works. What is exactly wrong for you?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov The words "Good Morning" should be appearing as it is morning time (the time I defined in the code). All it shows for me is ", name!"

Comment: Very strange. And what time was it exactly?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov It is right now 9:46 in my location. I define morning from 5:00 - 12:00.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/kjwgen6s/ I've removed unnecessary code and set the date explicitly to a "morning" time andit works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours() : '') + d.getHours(),
m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : '') + d.getMinutes();
```

What I see from these two lines, you are contacting hours and minutes twice into a string.

If it's 09:09am, the code above gets you `099` as `h`, `099` as `m`.

If you want to keep 0 at left padding, you can do this:

```
h = ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2),
m = ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
```

Now get back to your problem, you don't actually need to do 0-padding at all, just try the following:

```
function timeNow() {

    var d = new Date(),
    h = d.getHours(),

    // To check for a time range (between 4:: and 11:30 here):
    var morningTime = h >= 5 && h <= 12;
    var noonTime    = h > 12 && h <= 17;
    var nightTime   = h > 17 && h < 5;
    var greeting = "";

    if (morningTime) {
        greeting = "Good Morning";
    } else if (noonTime) {
        greeting = "Good Afternoon";
    } else if (nightTime) {
        greeting = "Good Evening";
    }

    return greeting;
}
document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow() + ', name!';
```

Comment: I believe since neither h nor m are used for output. this 0-padding is completely unnecessary..

Comment: @EduardMalakhov, I agree that `m` is not necessary, but `h` is. `morningTime`, `noonTime` and `nightTime` values depends on `h` which affects `greeting`

Comment: Yeah, but you don't need to pad an integer for comparison.

Comment: Ideally I would like to use the minutes, ie: 11:30 being the cut off for morning, but it isn't a big deal. Thanks!